# Declare Function from NotInheritable Class

Tags: vb.net, winforms, class, dll

I need to use an external DLL in my code without using project reference. I'm trying to use Declare Function on the scope of my project, but it doesn't work. If I use project reference for the DLL it works but I can't use this for the delivery.

The problem is that I need to declare the function for a NotInheritable Class, and when I'm declearing in my scope I can't get to that class. The DLL is in the same path of my application, currently in BIN\Debug project.

My lib is ***libfacturista*** and the NotInheritable Class is ***ansiApi***:

```
Namespace libfacturista
    Public NotInheritable Class ansiApi
    Public Shared Sub init()
    ...
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Using Porject reference the code works ok, :

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    libfacturista.ansiApi.init()
End Sub
```

But when I use declare on scope it doesn't work, even naming the function with class as prefix.

```
Declare Sub init Lib "libfacturista_cs.dll" Alias "init" ()
'Declare Sub init Lib "libfacturista_cs.dll" Alias "ansiApi.init" ()

Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    init()
Sub
```

Is there anyway I can Declare de function on the scope so I won't have to use project reference? How can I get to the NotInheritable Class?

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: `NotInheritable` is `sealed` in C#. `static` in C# is `Shared` in VB. If your dll is a .NET dll that contains `static class ansiApi`, then you need to reference it with the project references, and you cannot `Declare` it.

Comment: As GSerg says, VB,Net `NonInheritable` is not the same as C# `static`. Please [edit] your question to make clear whether the class is `NonInheritable`, or if it is `Shared`.

Comment: Edited, so it can be more clear.
When I create a C# project, reference the DLL and go for the MetaData the class is Static.
But when I do the same in VBNET the class is NotInheritable.

My project is in VBNET, I thought my comment was helpful, sorry.

Comment: What is the external dll?  Is it a .NET assembly, a COM dll, a C++-API dll, or a C-API dll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't reference the assembly in your project, you'd need to load it at runtime.

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Load the external assembly (dll)
    Dim externalAssembly As Reflection.Assembly = Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("libfacturista.dll")

    'Get the specific class that you are interested in
    Dim externalClass As Type = externalAssembly.GetType("libfacturista.ansiApi")
    'Access the method directly
    externalClass.GetMethod("init").Invoke(Nothing, Nothing)

    'Or...Create an instance of that class
    Dim instance As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(externalClass)
    'And access public methods from the class (methods will not show in intellisense)
    instance.init()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
The class is Abstract, the instance can't be created. Is there any way to use this class?

Comment: Ah, ok... ignore the `CreateInstance` try... `externalClass.GetMethod("init").Invoke(Nothing, Nothing)`